# Stop or Hide autocomplete text on registration login

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, autocomplete, woocommerce

I have a WordPress WooCommerce site.  The login and registration page is the same.  The issue I'm running into is that the saved username and passwords are autofilling the registration side of the page as well as the login side.  I tried setting autocomplete to off and false and nope.  I put it in the input field and the form.  I found that username and password autocomplete="off/false" settings are ignored now.

The autocomplete attribute and login fields
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

What can I do to hide the autocomplete on the registration login fields?  I'm considering separating the login and registration page but I'm not sure if the fields will still autofill.  Is there jquery or css that be used to stop registration inputs from autofilling?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/159462/how-to-disable-autocomplete-on-the-wp-login-php-page

You may have to enhance it to include all field IDs you want to disable autocomplete for. Of course, seeing the actual page will also help.

EDIT: try adding this to your functions.php

```
function wpse_no_login_autocomplete() {
 echo '<<<html
  <script>
   document.getElementById( "username" ).autocomplete = "off";
   document.getElementById( "password" ).autocomplete = "off";
  </script>
 html';
}

add_action( 'login_form', 'wpse_no_login_autocomplete' );


function wpse_no_reg_autocomplete() {
 echo '<<<html
  <script>
   document.getElementById( "reg_username" ).autocomplete = "off";
   document.getElementById( "reg_password" ).autocomplete = "off";
  </script>
 html';
}

add_action( 'register_form', 'wpse_no_reg_autocomplete' );
```

Comment: I edited the code, missed quotes in initial version. Try now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `document.getElementsByName("nameOfYourInput")[0].autocomplete="off"`

Comment: How does this differ from having autocomplete set to off/false in the html input?  Also how does this work around what Mozilla stated that login field autocomplete settings are ignored by the browser?